# Can't display block in panel

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-panels

I'm new to drupal, and very new to panels. I have a custom module which displays rss feed items based on user taxonomy. It displays the correct info as a block, but it needs to be on the users' dashboard page, which uses panels. When I try to insert it, it is always blank.

The code inserts a default view I already created, showing all feed items (1_feeds_defaults_feed_items) into a block. I can't edit it to work in a panel. I imagine that there are 10 different things I may have done wrong, but have tried every permutation I can think of.

```
<?php
//.this function generates a block and calls the second 
//function for the content of this block

function custom_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
switch ($op) {
case 'list':
  $block[0]['info'] = 'Custom View';
        $block[2]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;

  return $block;
   break;
case 'view':

            switch ($delta) {
      case 0:
        $block['subject'] = '';
        $block['content'] = custom_userfeeds() ;
        break;
    }

  return $block;
}
}


function custom_userfeeds() {
//finds the user id from argument on user page.  
//You can also find the user id the way the page you linked me to did, 
//but if you do it the way I am below it would allow admins 
//to view other users feeds
$uid = arg(1);
//loads the profile node -- 'profile' is the profile content type.

$node = content_profile_load('profile', $uid);
//find the terms associated with the user's profile

if ($node && $node->taxonomy) {
foreach($node->taxonomy as $term) {
  $terms[] = $term->tid;
}
}

//embeds a view with those terms passed to it.  
View display is something like block_1 or page_1
if($terms) {
$t = implode('+',$terms);
 return views_embed_view("1_feeds_defaults_feed_items","page_1", $t);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it in a view:
-Add Argument -> Taxonomy -> Taxonomy Term ID
-Provide default argument
-PHP Code
-PHP argument code:

```
global $user;
$query = "SELECT tid FROM {term_user} WHERE uid = %d";
$result = db_query($query, $user->uid);
if ($result) {
  $terms = array();
  while ($term = db_fetch_array($result)) {
  $terms[] = $term['tid'];
  }
if ($terms) {
   $termargs = implode("+", $terms);
   return $termargs;
  }
}
 else {
 return FALSE;
}
```

-Check "Allow multiple terms per argument."